# Actions and Parameters are not detected after creating an intent

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x26dR.png)I send intents with entities using API, but the set entities was not shown on the dialogflow....

I tried to insert the 'entityType', 'alias' to 'trainingPhrases'.

```
 trainingPhrases: [
    {
      type: 'EXAMPLE',
      parts: [
        {
          text: intent.question,
          entityType: '@pizza',
          alias: 'pizza',
        },
      ],
    },
```

.........

```
const parameter1 = [
  {
    displayName: 'pizza',
    value: 'pizza',
    entityTypeDisplayName: '@pizza',
    mandatory: true,
  },
]
// TODO
await this.intentsClient.batchUpdateIntents({
  parent: intentParent,
  languageCode,
  intentBatchInline: {
    intents: this.intents,
  },
  parameters: parameter1,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create the entity through the API as well?

I do this through the API as well (creating the entity + creating the intent, not by batch though):

Creating the entity:

```
exports.createEntity = async function(entityId, tags) {
    let aTags = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        let tTags = {};
        let aSyn = [];
        aSyn.push(tags[i].text);

        tTags['value'] = tags[i].text;
        tTags['synonyms'] = aSyn;
        aTags.push(tTags);
    }
    const entityType = {
        displayName: entityId,
        kind: 'KIND_MAP',
        entities: aTags
    };

    const entityRequest = {
        parent: agentPath,
        entityType: entityType
    };

    const responses = await entitiesClient.createEntityType(entityRequest);
    console.log(`Intent ${responses[0].name} created`);
};
```

And this is how I created the intents afterwards:

```
// The path to identify the agent that owns the created intent.
const agentPath = intentsClient.projectAgentPath(projectId);

const trainingPhrases = [];

const part = {
    text: tag1.text,
    entityType: '@' + entityId,
    alias: entityId,
};

const part1 = {
    text: tag2.text,
    entityType: '@' + entityId,
    alias: entityId,
};

const partX = {
    text: "news about ",
};

// Here we create a new training phrase for each provided part.
const trainingPhrase = {
    type: 'EXAMPLE',
    parts: [part],
};

const trainingPhrase1 = {
    type: 'EXAMPLE',
    parts: [part1]
};

const trainingPhrase2 = {
    type: 'EXAMPLE',
    parts: [partX, part]
};

const trainingPhrase3 = {
    type: 'EXAMPLE',
    parts: [partX, part1]
};

trainingPhrases.push(trainingPhrase);
trainingPhrases.push(trainingPhrase1);
trainingPhrases.push(trainingPhrase2);
trainingPhrases.push(trainingPhrase3);

const parameter = {
    displayName: entityId + "x1",
    entityTypeDisplayName: '@' + entityId,
    value: tag1.text,
};

const parameter1 = {
    displayName: entityId + "x2",
    entityTypeDisplayName: '@' + entityId,
    value: tag2.text,
};

const messageText = {
    text: 'messageText',
};

const message = {
    text: messageText,
};

const intent = {
    displayName: entityId,
    trainingPhrases: trainingPhrases,
    parameters: [parameter, parameter1],
};

const createIntentRequest = {
    parent: agentPath,
    intent: intent,
};

// Create the intent
const responses = await intentsClient.createIntent(createIntentRequest);
```

Hope this can somehow help you.

Comment: Thanks for comment.
Yes.. also entities is created in API.. that is work?

Comment: Yes, so did I. I updated my answer with how I created entities. Keep in mind that in specific use case I always had to create new entities for each new intent that I created.

Comment: thanks,. I got it. But, I'd comment out all of code which creating entities, and create entites in the Dialogflow web. So, i'm just create intent and send its. But, your advice is 'create entity -> create intent' in synchronously right  ?

Comment: That's how I did it. If you have to create lots of intents at once then it's better to the it with the batchCreate. However, I didn't need that in my use case so I don't recommend doing it synchronously if you have lots and lots of intents to create.

Comment: That's why I using batchUpdateIntents, I have a lots of intents. but, it didn't work just only one intent. I thinks I have same logic with you.